# htaccess redirect ignored with rewriteengine

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a htaccess question that I think may be so simple (dumb?) that no one has had to ask it before. I converted from using html pages to php and for the most part the following has worked:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ /htmlrewrite.php?page=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

There are a couple of exceptions though so I assumed putting:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.htm http://example.com/newpage.php
```

above the IfMofule... would do the trick but it doesn't. The "Redirect 301" is being ignored unless I remove the rest of the code. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using mod_rewrite and mod_alias together and they are both getting applied to the same URL. You should stick with either mod_rewrite or mod_alias.

mod_rewrite: (remove the `Redirect` directive)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^oldpage.htm$ http://example.com/newpage.php [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ /htmlrewrite.php?page=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

mod_alias: (remove everything in the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Redirect 301 /oldpage.htm http://example.com/newpage.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)\.htm$ /htmlrewrite.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache processes mod_rewrite (Rewrite*) first and then mod_alias (Redirect).

Use `RewriteCond` to prevent /oldpage.htm from processed by mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oldpage\.htm$
RewriteRule ^(.+).htm$ /htmlrewrite.php?page=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Or use `RewriteRule` instead of `Redirect`.

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.htm$ http://example.com/newpage.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+).htm$ /htmlrewrite.php?page=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've gone for the second option as there are about 20 of the line 1's already there. Am attempting to mark it as the right answer but stackoverflow keeps reporting an error.